# Resizing images on Windows Phone 7 on thread pool thread?

Tags: c#, .net, image, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 app that deals with a lot of images - These images can range from a few hundred pixels up to 1080P (Potentially higher in future).

Images are very resource intensive so I've gone down the path of caching + resizing images on the phone before displaying them.

This means on first time setup after a user has entered the IP address of the image store I can ask them to wait a few minutes while it's all retrieved/resized/cached. From then on they can have nice and snappy performance.

At the moment my cache manager tracks Images by a dictionary of Uri's and file locations. I have a Queue that processes up to 5 images at a time (Async web requests, resizing is semi done on thread pool thread).

The problem I have is that the WritableBitmap class in Silverlight is a UI element, meaning I have to transition to the UI thread via the Dispatcher to do the actual resizing which is stupid and slows the whole thing down - It also means my Cache Manager is effectively single threaded.

So it goes Cache Manager (Thread Pool) -> Async Web request (Thread Pool) -> Callback (Thread Pool) -> Resizing (UI Thread) -> Marking cache job as complete (Thread Pool).

I've been looking for a 3rd party library that will A) Compile and run on Windows Phone 7 and B) Be able to resize images of various formats by manipulating a stream or byte array and not be dependent on the UI thread.

Any one had any experience with this?

Cheers,

Tyler

Comment: Any chance of using a web service to resize the images as you download them?

Comment: They're coming from an external system that I have no control over =/

Comment: You could pass the Url to a webservice which would do the download+resize and then pass the smaller image back to windows phone? I think that's what Damian was saying.

Comment: Ah right, that would be far too slow sorry. The actual act of resizing them is kind of fast enough as it is... I just know it could so SO much faster if I didn't have to transition to the UI thread to do it. I just need a library thats happy working with png and jpegs at the byte level that can be used on threads other than the UI.

Comment: I've been searching all day and haven't found anything yet - I did find LeadTools which is a massive suit of imaging tools that support WP7 - http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/silverlight/windows-phone.htm - Their resizing classes can be run on background threads but unfortunately it was A) Slower than WriteableBitmap by quite a lot and B) It looks like at some point they're transitioning to the UI thread during the resize anyway (Screen flashes white - Good sign the UI thread is being held up).

Comment: I've put in an answer - about using a web service... with a few suggestions. However, I'm not sure I entirely understand your question... Can I ask for a few clarifications? 1) How many different sizes do you want to output for each image? 2) I'm guessing not, but can you just use the MediaLibrary on the phone? This would give you thumbnails "for free". 3) Have you actually profiled the processing? From what you've said it feels odd that the resizing is actually a problem - in a mobile situation I would expect the image download to actually be your bottleneck.

Comment: The application is intended to be used over wifi, the user will be abke to browse their Xbox Media Center library as well as remote control (Play, pause etc.) their media center. The images range from 1080P backgrounds down to audio album cover art and dvd cover art etc. The reason the resizing is the bottleneck is again due to being used over wifi the images get to the phone very quickly. I MUST resize and cache images due to the large number and size, I let users scroll through lists that contain thumbnails and without resizing this will essentially crash the application (Runs out of memory)

Comment: I'm at the point now we're I have performance at 100% and extremely happy with it, however I force users to wait while I run an initial cache job when they very first enter the IP address of Xbox Media Center. Depending on the size of their library I could see this job getting close to 10 minutes (My library with 300 movies and 20 odd tv seasons takes about 1 minute). So I'm really hoping to speed up the caching as much as possible.

Comment: Hi. I'm more familiar with WPF on Windows. It is legal to do so there (with some specific restrictions). At what point does it fail whey you use WritableBitmap on worker threads?

Comment: I did it like this: created and configured the WriteableBitmap on the UI-thread then switched to background worker and called SaveJpeg. That works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

In order to reduce the download size and in order to remove the burden of processing from the phone CPU, then I'd push this work out to a web service.

For example, you could host a service like the open source WebImageResizer code somewhere online http://webimageresizer.codeplex.com/  - e.g. on a free AppHarbor server.

Or you could use a commercial (freemium) service like:

- http://webresizer.com/app/
- http://www.appspotimage.com/

Either of these would enable you to rapidly process the images on a server with a superfast connection and to juse deliver smaller images to the phone with its limited data connection.

Comment: This isn't feasible for my application sorry. The application is an Xbox Media Center remote, it's intended to be used over Wifi (It can be used over 3G etc. but there isn't much point). I really don't want to force people to have their Media Library images uploaded to a web service then back to thier phone to use my app. I also don't want to require them to have an internet connection to use my app,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand what you're saying... I don't think you're going to get any improvement by changing this away from the UI thread. You may be able to make it faster by finding a faster resizing algorithm, but the "single threaded" wording in your question isn't the problem - fundamentally you are on a phone with a single CPU with a single core (and some graphics processing available from the UI).

Comment: Only ways i can think to make this feel faster are: 1) show the users some feedback during the caching, 2) let the users start using the app (with placekitten thumbnails) before the caching is complete, 3) look at the Media Center API again - is there any way of asking it for thumbnails?, 4) as well as resizing, take a look at the image decoder libraries to see if the downloaded images already contain thumbnails (e.g. JPEGs often have thumbs embedded in the JFIF stream). Sorry in advance - as my guess is that you've already tried all of these things!

Comment: 1) The user currently gets a screen explaining why caching is needed and a counter of how many images are left to cache - I thought if I presented the reasons then hopefully they might not mind as much. 2) I can't let them use the app until caching is complete as when the images are cached/resized the resizing is done on the UI thread (See first post) so they would get unacceptable UI stutter without knowing why. 3) No way of asking Xbox Media Center for smaller images and finally 4) Thats not a bad idea will have to look in to that :). Screen shot of cache screen here: http://imgup.co.nz/1751

Comment: Cool :) On 1) if you show a new image every few seconds then they might enjoy the message even more. On 2) looking at your screenshots, I think on demand image processing might be possible instead of up front download... but fundamentally this is all your choice. Good luck whatever you decide!

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com) library both supports WP7 and suports image resizing, so you might have more success using this.

Comment: ImageTools does not support PNG on WP7 and also does not provide any resizing utilities that I could find (They do provide an interface but no implementations).

Comment: If you take a look at the latest version in source control (on CodePlex) it has a PNG implementation on WP7 now. Resize functionality is provided in the ExtendedImage_Operations class file as a static `Resize` method on the `ExtendedImage` class.

Comment: Unfourtunatley the Resize method takes an IImageResizer interface as a parameter, and there don't appear to be any implementations of IImageResizer that I can see.

Comment: The default `IImageResizer` is the `ImageTools.Filtering.NearestNeighborResizer`, which is in the ImageTools.Filtering assembly (and is also available under WP7).

Comment: Hmm it's throwing exceptions all over the place and slow as hell (No documentation so I may be doing something wrong but it's throwing exceptions when I simply try to set the image source to a memory stream). I'm starting to think the Silverlight WriteableBitmap class executes at least its resizing code natively and/or is hardware accelerated as no third party solution has come close yet (Even though they're running on their own threads).

Answer (score 0):

Try http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ created by Réne Schulte. It has a way better performance as the WriteableBitmap that is shipped with the SDK.

Comment: Still relies on WriteableBitmap which is a UI element so doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: actually WriteableBitmap's SaveJpeg method can be called off the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Are files you want to display on your server?

If yes, in my opinion you have chosen the wrong approach to this problem. It's pointless to transfer heavy images, then resize them. I recommend keeping them in either low and high resolution on the server.

If not, I can't help you. I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/resizing-images-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) but I think you have already seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Tyler - You mention that on initial launch, the application does retrieve the images from an IP address (on the internet I presume)?

> This means on first time setup after a user has entered the IP address of the image store I can ask them to wait a few minutes while it's all retrieved/resized/cached. From then on they can have nice and snappy performance.

If that is correct, what I think some of the answers have suggested in creating a proxy is actually a feasible solution. I would structure it like this:

Your App -> Web Request to Proxy Handler

```
string imageUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://[user's_ip]/path_to_image.png");
http://domain.com/your_proxy.ashx?users_image_url=imageUrl
```

Your proxy handler on the back end should request the image, resize it, and return the resized image back to your application.

Your App -> Cache the Returned Resized Image

Loop as needed...

UPDATED:

It turns out there is a way to resize images on WP7 outside of the UI thread using the native WriteableBitmap class. There is a method called .SaveJpeg() that allows this, and we're using it currently in our WP7 application CitySourced. Your code should look something like this:

```
wb.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, orientation, quality);
```

The only bummer is that it only works by writing a .JPG file and there's no .PNG support. Let me know if this works for your use case.

Comment: On a side note, I would presume the server would be able to resize the image much faster than the device, so this would probably be a faster solution than having the device handle the resizing. Additionally, the resized image would arrive to the device faster than downloading the original, larger image.

Comment: Nice try but you didn't read the rest of the comments did you? :p My application is used on a home network over wifi. I don't want to build in a need for the internet.

Comment: You could build the handler to work on an intranet website (accessible via private ip address or hosts file modification) and it would work the same as if it were a public facing handler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is performance so much but how you are going about displaying the images. I think it would be better to always showing a default thumbnail and then update the thumbnail once it has been resized by your background job. The app should be usable much more quickly.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.dtksoft.com/dtkimage.php
This works with all file formats, and is compatible with windows Mobile

Comment: Doesn't mention WP7 support, isn't free, you don't sound like you have any personal experience with it so I guess you can't comment on speed etc.